# flutter localization error when set title

Tags: flutter, localization

localizaed.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class Localized {
  Localized(this.locale);

  final Locale locale;

  static Localized of(BuildContext context) => Localizations.of<Localized>(context, Localized);
  static Map<String, Map<String,String>> _v = {
    'en': {
      'title': 'hello world',
    },
    'ja': {
      'title': 'こんちは'
    }
  };
  String get title => _v[locale.languageCode]['title'];
}

class LocalizedDelagate extends LocalizationsDelegate<Localized> {
  const LocalizedDelagate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => ['en','ja'].contains(locale.languageCode);
  @override
  Future<Localized> load(Locale locale) async => Localized(locale);
  @override
  bool shouldReload(LocalizationsDelegate old) => false;
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:calculator/src/localization/localized.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:calculator/src/pages/HomePage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

void main() => runApp(StockCalcApp());

class StockCalcApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        const LocalizedDelagate(),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en'),
        const Locale('ja'),
      ],
      onGenerateTitle: (BuildContext context) => Localized.of(context).title, // notthing problem
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.pink),
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(Localized.of(context).title), // and same code but, error. when I comment this line then, nothing well.
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink[900],
          elevation: 0.0,
        ),
        body: StockHome(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I cannot understand why to occur an error this message on the screen.

```
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'title' was called on null.
```

I just do this example find on the web. and I think.. is very simple .. I think.
but seriously I cannot understand why to bring up this message on the android emulator.

Comment: Have you defined a `Localized` for your `MaterialApp`? When you do `Localized.of(context)` it attempts to retrieve the closest ancestor of `Localized` in your Widget tree. Typically you define in `localizationDelegates` in your `MaterialApp` the class that will be used as a delegate.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `onGenerateTitle: (BuildContext context) => Localized.of(context).title`, it uses a new `BuildContext`, which already contains the `LocalizedDelagate()`, so it can be called with `Localized.of(context)`.

When you use it within the same `build` method, you refer to an instance of `context` **before** the `LocalizedDelagate()` was created, so `Localized.of(context)` doesn't return anything.

You can avoid this problem by creating a new Widget, which will have an updated `BuildContext` in it's `build` method, that will have access to `Localized`.
For example, create a new widget named `HomeScreen`

```
class StockCalcApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        const LocalizedDelagate(),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en'),
        const Locale('ja'),
      ],
      onGenerateTitle: (BuildContext context) => Localized.of(context).title, 
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.pink),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(Localized.of(context).title), // this context will have access to Localized
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink[900],
          elevation: 0.0,
        ),
        body: StockHome(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: wow...  really? I get it @dumazy and I was a test and good well. best answer! thank you

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you :)

Comment: I spent all day on this... boom. James as @yon I get why now which is even more useful!